# SecureChannelFailure when calling service

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am getting the following Exception. However, problem is that I don't know exactly where in my code it is happening.

I have a try/catch in all of my tasks.

Any ideas?

```
08:22:22 - Error in TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException: 
A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

Inner exception: An error occurred while sending the request
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00486] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000f3] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
Inner exception: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0041e] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
Inner exception: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0006a] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
Inner exception: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Net.Sockets.SocketError& errorCode) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005f] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 

Inner exception: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'..
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00113] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.BeginSendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00026] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00027] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (System.Exception& ex) [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
Inner exception: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socket_flags, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x000b4] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
08:22:22 - Error in TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException:  System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Net.Sockets.SocketError& errorCode) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005f] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socket_flags, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x000b4] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00113] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.BeginSendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00026] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00027] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (System.Exception& ex) [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0006a] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0041e] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00486] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000f3] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Net.Sockets.SocketError& errorCode) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005f] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socket_flags, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x000b4] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00113] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.BeginSendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00026] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x00000] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00027] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (System.Exception& ex) [0x00021] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0006a] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in <35fb91e7655f4c71acdb8be6fa48e655>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0041e] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00486] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <ce978ecf81d8475694da9acbd4ed2610>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000f3] in <f3da26af63564157b82209f8aeeeae05>:0 <---
```

Comment: The important part is: `Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)`. Make sure the service you are calling uses a proper SSL/TLS configuration. What HttpClientHandler are you using?

Comment: @Cheesebaron i am not using HttpClientHandler. should i use it ? the crash occurs  at sporadic times

Comment: Are you on the same network when this happens? If you are in an enterprise environment, odds are that your sysadmins are doing SSL interception. Did you manage to get a valid call to the same URL? As @Cheesbaron states, the `SecureChannelFailure` is the root of the problem.